# How to add a multihead attention layer to a CNN-LSTM model?

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network, lstm, attention-model, multihead-attention

I'm trying to make a hybrid binary text classification model using a multi-head attention mechanism with CNN-LSTM. However, I'm facing an issue when trying to pass the values obtained from CNN-LSTM to the attention layer.

This was what I tried:

Here's the code for defining multihead attention layer.

```
class TransformerBlock(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, embed_dim, num_heads, ff_dim, rate=0.1):
        super().__init__()
        self.att = layers.MultiHeadAttention(num_heads=num_heads, key_dim=embed_dim)
        self.ffn = keras.Model(
            [layers.Dense(ff_dim, activation="relu"), layers.Dense(embed_dim),]
        )
        self.layernorm1 = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)
        self.layernorm2 = layers.LayerNormalization(epsilon=1e-6)
        self.dropout1 = layers.Dropout(rate)
        self.dropout2 = layers.Dropout(rate)

    def call(self, inputs, training):
        attn_output = self.att(inputs, inputs)
        attn_output = self.dropout1(attn_output, training=training)
        out1 = self.layernorm1(inputs + attn_output)
        ffn_output = self.ffn(out1)
        ffn_output = self.dropout2(ffn_output, training=training)
        return self.layernorm2(out1 + ffn_output)
```

This one is for positional encoding and tokenization

```
class TokenAndPositionEmbedding(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, maxlen, vocab_size, embed_dim):
        super().__init__()
        self.token_emb = layers.Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim=embed_dim)
        self.pos_emb = layers.Embedding(input_dim=maxlen, output_dim=embed_dim)

    def call(self, x):
        maxlen = tf.shape(x)[-1]
        positions = tf.range(start=0, limit=maxlen, delta=1)
        positions = self.pos_emb(positions)
        x = self.token_emb(x)
        return x + positions
```

Defining the whole arhitecture

```
inputs = layers.Input(shape=(maxlen,))
embedding_layer = TokenAndPositionEmbedding(maxlen, vocab_size, embed_dim)
x = embedding_layer(inputs)
x = Conv1D(256, 3, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = MaxPooling1D(3)(x)
x = Conv1D(128, 3, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = LSTM(64, return_sequences=True)(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = LSTM(32)(x)
x = TransformerBlock(256, num_heads, ff_dim)(x)
x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.1)(x)
x = layers.Dense(20, activation="relu")(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.1)(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)

model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
```

The error

```
StagingError                              Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-19-ea38c3c52d0e> in <module>
     10 x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
     11 x = LSTM(32)(x)
---> 12 x = TransformerBlock(256, num_heads, ff_dim)(x)
     13 x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(x)
     14 x = layers.Dropout(0.1)(x)

1 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    690       except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    691         if hasattr(e, 'ag_error_metadata'):
--> 692           raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    693         else:
    694           raise

StagingError: Exception encountered when calling layer "transformer_block" (type TransformerBlock).

in user code:

    File "<ipython-input-17-4c5de9a08c11>", line 14, in call  *
        attn_output = self.att(inputs, inputs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler  **
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/keras/layers/activation/softmax.py", line 98, in call
        return backend.softmax(inputs, axis=self.axis[0])

    IndexError: Exception encountered when calling layer "softmax" (type Softmax).
    
    tuple index out of range
    
    Call arguments received by layer "softmax" (type Softmax):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 8), dtype=float32)
      • mask=None


Call arguments received by layer "transformer_block" (type TransformerBlock):
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 32), dtype=float32)
  • training=False
```

Comment: I tried ```padding="same"``` as another hyperparameter for the CNN layers, but that hasn't resolved it. I also tried matching the output size from the LSTM as the ```embed_dim``` for the ```TransformerBlock``` constructor as well, and that didn't work either.

Comment: Forgot to mention one thing: the transformer block works when there are no CNN or LSTM layers prior to it, and the error is occurring when any other layer is added prior to the transformer layer in the architecture.